# Excel VBA - Move rows if time/date in column is more than 6 hours ago

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not sure if this is possible? I'm trying to move items from my list that haven't been touched in the last six hours to a new sheet to be worked. How do I copy/move rows using a formula instead of just a match text scenario?

My code so far:

```
With Sheets("Scheduled")
    .Select
    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(2).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
       With .Cells(Lrow, "C")
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If .Value <> "Scheduled" Then
                    'Copy all "Not Scheduled" reports to the "Tracker" sheet and remove them from "Scheduled".
                    .EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Tracker").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    .EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next Lrow
End With
```

This code isn't exactly the section I'm talking about, but this is how I'm moving rows around other parts of the workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change the `C` column letter in,

   ```
   With .Cells(Lrow, "C")
   ```

   ...to the column letter with the datetime value you want to check.
2. Change,

   ```
     If Not IsError(.Value) Then
   ```

   ... to,

   ```
     If IsNumeric(.Value) Then   'this also moves blanks
   ```
3. Change the comparison from,

   ```
        If .Value <> "Scheduled" Then
   ```

   ... to,

   ```
        If .Value2 < (Now - TimeSerial(6, 0, 0)) Then
   ```
4. Change the `Tracker` worksheet name in,

   ```
         .EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Tracker").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
   ```

   ... to whatever the destination worksheet's name is.

Comment: Step 3 seems to be what I was looking for. Thank you! I'll have to test it out tomorrow